# How to structure a .net azure function app to use as an web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, azure-functions

I'm planning to use azure functions (c#) to create my API. In that API it will have multiple endpoints like CRUD.

Now my question is should I put all those functions(endpoint) in one class file (like [this one](https://github.com/Usman-Sheikh/RestFunctionApp/blob/master/TaskApi.cs)) or each function in its own class (one file for Create, one file for Read....)?

Are there any drawbacks for having multiple functions inside the same class file?

Comment: What draws you towards functions in contrast to for example Minimal API ? (Just curious)

Comment: Our API gonna be a complex one with a bit of logic and many entities, here I just give a simple example to ask the question. We are also not sure whether we should deploy a container to app service or just build our API via azure functions. Still compare these 2 options, but can not find a major difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there any drawbacks for having multiple functions inside the same class file?

There are no big drawbacks in having multiple Azure Functions inside the same class, but I would recommend you create the separate Azure Function class for each case instead.

Or if you have same case/functionality being used in all your ***functions***, then create a common class and that should be injected in all the Azure Function classes.

As per my experience, individual functions for each case/functionality will give you the better logging details which reduces the risk in Production slots/environments where it is that easy to identify the logs/monitor for each Azure Functions.

Also, during the maintenance time - if one individual function is affected, it will not affect the other function classes whereas in the same class file, there is a chance to affect the other functions written for other functionalities.

Comment: Thanks @VenkatesanSettu-MT,  we are trying to use the azure functions as web api, so CRUD will be represented by 4 azure functions. Even in this case, do you still suggest us separate each endpoint into its own file? (like Create in its file, Update in its file). I was planning to do a controller like structure, basically have all the endpoints(functions) in the same class file.

Comment: Yes You can do a controller-like structure in Azure Functions that allows you to do it within the same function class!